# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch') error | Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, event-handling

I was coding an advanced event handler in discord.js using a YouTube channel's code. And in one of the many files, I got an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')`. Here is the code of the file.

```
module.exports = async (client, guildId) => {
  let applicationCommands;

  if (guildId) {
    const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(guildId);
    applicationCommands = guild.commands;
  } else {
    applicationCommands = await client.application.commands;
  }

  await applicationCommands.fetch();
  return applicationCommands;
};
```

**Please write a reply if I need to do any npm installation or such.**
Thanks.

Comment: at which fetch you are getting the error

Comment: I'm not too sure about that.. I'm also trying to find out which fetch is causing the problem, but yeah.. I don't know which is causing trouble.

Comment: The error trace stack will tell you at what file and line the error comes from. Also, make sure `client` is truely a Client instance and not an unexpected value

Comment: What is "the error trace stack"? Is it some kind of VSCode extension or something? Also yes, `client` is a true Client instance.

Comment: We need to see/know at which line of the code the fetch is failing at... giving us just the error gives no indication as you have multiple `.fetch()` in above code, but I would assume it is your  `await applicationCommands.fetch();` as I'm unsure what are you trying to fetch right there?

Comment: It's the second `.fetch()` line. Because `await client.guilds.fetch(guildId);` works perfectly, giving me info about the server, when I do `console.log(guild). But when I console log `applicationCommands`, it gives me `undefined`. So I believe that the `await applicationCommands.fetch();` gives me the error. I also copy this code from a YouTuber named "Under Ctrl" on his discordjsv14 tutorial. So I dont really know since I am a noob.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to fetch guilds as they already cached in `discord.js`.
   To get a guild:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('guildId');
```

2. Fetch your application commands altogether instead of 2 different statements:

```js
const applicationCommands = await client.application.commands.fetch();
```

If it's still `undefined`, consider fetching the application:

```js
await client.application.fetch()
```